# Sendkeys Ctrl+S in Powershell / Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell

I'm using:

```
start-sleep -Milliseconds 100
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^{S}')
```

Is it the right syntax because I have "Save As" instead of "Save" for a file that is already named in VSCode.

Comment: Why are you sending keystrokes to VS code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the following syntaxes:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for Save: `^s`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for Save As: `^S` or `^+s`

The syntax which you shared also sends <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. But you don't need to use `{}` around `S`. 
For more information about the syntax, see: [Remarks section of SendKeys.Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx#Anchor_2).